# Search Autocomplete

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest

I've been making a custom SharePoint Web Page and I had a basic search bar that searches either Google or our SharePoint site depending on which of two radio buttons are selected upon searching.  If the SharePoint button is selected, I would like to have search suggestions pop up based on user input. Is this possible to automate in SharePoint?  Most guides I've seen online are performed by populating a list and then pulling suggestions from that list, but this is not what I am looking for. I'm looking for actual suggestions from the site collection.

*This is using Sharepoint 2013 Service Pack 1

Comment: what is your sharepoint version?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013, Service Pack 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, If you configure the search services application(which i am sure you did).

You need to configure the Query suggestions.To add phrases that you want the search system to always or never suggest to users as they start typing a query, you have to create one or several text files that contain these phrases, and then import the files into the search system.

Here is the guide from TechNet. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721441.aspx

Once you configure the suggestion, than make sure the “prepare query suggestion" timer job executed successfully to update this.

Comment: Can this be applied to the custom input field I have? Or would I have to include Sharepoint's search bar for this to work?

Comment: what you mean by custom search bar, it is getting the data from same place correct

Comment: Currently it is a simple input field and upon submission opens a new tab to Sharepoint Search with their search query.

Comment: ok then its not easy, you have to perform customization as you mentioned in your question.check this one http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/04/30/sharepoint-2013-autocomplete-textboxes-using-the-term-store-and-csom.aspx

Comment: Okay I'll keep this in mind, thank you so much for the help Waqas!